# Coverting 2020-05-30 20:12:23 into just 2020-05-30 in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have a variable called datetime with values that look like this **2020-05-30 20:12:23** and I want to convert them into just **2020-05-30**. In other words, I want to get rid of the time value.

I am trying to use the as.Date function, but that does not seem to be working.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `as.Date("2020-05-30 20:12:23")`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas When I try this it gives me the same error: Error in as.Date.default(., datetime) : do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”

Comment: Are you running that in a pipe?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I was, just tried running it outside of the pipe and it works better but for some reason, it keeps converting my 2020-04-30 20:12:23 into 2020-05-01. Is it rounding up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following is more `dplyr`-idiomatic than the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72605435/8245406).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

query1 <- data.frame(datetime = c("2021-04-30 19:20:27", "2020-05-30 20:12:23"))

datetimedf <- query1 %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(datetime, tz = '')) %>%
  select(date)

datetimedf
#>         date
#> 1 2021-04-30
#> 2 2020-05-30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this! Definitely a lot clearer and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  date = "2020-05-30 20:12:23"
)
```

Sample data

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  date               
  <chr>              
1 2020-05-30 20:12:23
```

Convert to date without time

```
df %>%  
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  date      
  <date>    
1 2020-05-30
```

Comment: This seems to working quite well, however, for a datetime value of 2021-04-30 19:20:27, it is converting to 2021-05-01. Is the function rounding up for some reason?

Comment: @JohnTayson Wierd, I couldn't replicate the problem. It is converted correctly on my side. I am really not sure.

Comment: @JohnTayson What is your timezone?

Comment: @JohnTayson GMT+2 Norway. Instead, maybe you can try as_date from lubridate package.

Comment: I am US Central GMT-5